# How to pass value from page to User Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using one user control in a page.
Basically after login this page is coming with user control.
I wanted pass the user name in that user control from login page.

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using? If your "login page" is implementing Forms Authentication, for instance, then you already have access to the current user.

Comment: Sir, i am able to access the current user after login but problem is that i wanted to show user name in User Control

Comment: Which user name would you like to display? You want to display it before the user is logged in?

Comment: Shouldn't you be storing user info in a session anyways?

Comment: it store in session and i am passing with session only

Comment: You can mark my answer correct if you think my answer worked or helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Say for you store the login name in a `LABEL` somewhere on the main page. Like this:

```
lblLogin.Text = "LoginName";
```

Now, on the user control you have another `LABEL` called **lblWCLogin** where you want to assign the login name from Parent page. Do something like this:

```
Label lblTextFromParentPageLabel = this.Parent.FindControl("lblLogin"); 
lblWCLogin = lblTextFromParentPageLabel.Text;
```

**Another Approach (does not matter if you have a MasterPage or not) is to Use Sessions.**

Set session on you Page or MasterPage code behind. Like this:

```
Session["LoginName"] = "Some User Name";
```

Retrive the session value on UserControl like this:

```
string login_name = (string)(Session["LoginName"]);
Label1.Text = login_name;
```

Comment: this should be on page load of master page?

Comment: Ok, you did not mention that you have masterpage.

Comment: ohh i am really sorry.It is not master page

Comment: i mean to say it should be on page load of parent page?

Comment: Yes, lblLogin.Text = "LoginName"; should be on parent page.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this

1. As one is to find the control
2. Store value in session and set the value from that session
3. Create public method of user control which will set the value of your label.. and call that userControl.SetPageLabel() method from your page at your desired places....

Make sure you have your label is in the update panel other wise label text will be changed but not visible on the screen...

Or you can use some javascript to set the label...

http://center4code.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

My suggestion is create a Property field in the user control which allow you to read or write value from any page that refer to the user control.

Comment: And how do I do this?